# When need to detrend the time-series data?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, trend

I am new to time-series models. I read many books, tutorial, relative questions, and published papers. However, I still confused about the detrended term. I would like to know when I need to detrend my data and when I do not need to do so. So, my questions are:

1- Do all time-series data need to be detrended before analysis?

2- What is the purpose of detrended the data?

3- When I must detrend my data and when I do not need to do so?

For example, suppose I am interesting in studying the affect of the weather (cold-hot) on the spread of influenza. So, do I need to detrend my data? And why?

Comment: Many time series models have an asssumption that series are stationary. A series with a trend is not stationary, and removing the trend is required to make stationary. (Obs: detrending may not be sufficient to make a series stationary)

Comment: @Daniel R thank you a lot for your comment. So, can I  said that the detrended the data is due to the model requirements and not because the data is time-series?

Comment: @DanielR, instead of commenting, you should have answered the question. Many times, people ignore comments!